# How to send a message to an object in lldb console?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, lldb

Say that I have the pointer to an object '`0x20c28010`'. How can I send this object a message in the debugger console (lldb)? As in: `[0x20c28010 doSomething];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the message doesn't return anything, or returns a pointer, an integer or a floating-point type that you don't care about, you can do this:

```
p (void)[0x20c28010 doSomething]
```

If you care about the return type, or the return type is a `struct`, you need to cast to the correct return type.  Examples:

```
p (int)[0x20c28010 length]
p (float)[0x20c28010 scale]
p (CGPoint)[0x20c28010 origin]
```

If the message returns a pointer to an Objective-C object or Core Foundation type, you can use `po` to print the returned object's description:

```
po [0x20c28010 doSomething]
```

Comment: Just a warning about this - this will result in any side-effects being executed as well, for the running application

Comment: Is it possible to send a parameter to the message. For instance [0x20c28010 doSomethingWith:0x1231231]???