# Xcode -How to interact with lldb address and send messages

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

I am debugging my app in lldb and need to send messages to objects.
I don't have the object variable name (i.e. self.object) rather an address to that object.
So for instance I have a `UIGestureRecognizer` which variable I don't have access to and has an address like:

```
0x7fe110297360
```

I want to send it a message that works with gesture recogniser:

```
[gestureA requireGestureToFail:gestureB];
```

So I translate that to a few variations - each unsuccessful:

```
expr [0x7fe110297360 requireGestureToFail:0x7fe10e842c00]
expr (long)[((id)0x7fe110297360) requireGestureToFail:((id)0x7fe10e842c00)]
expr -- [0x7fe110297360 requireGestureToFail:0x7fe10e842c00]
expr -- (long)[((id)0x7fe110297360) requireGestureToFail:((id)0x7fe10e842c00)]
expr [((id)0x7fe110297360) requireGestureToFail:((id)0x7fe10e842c00)]
```

each is acknowledged with an error:

```
error: warning: receiver type 'long' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'
error: no known method '-requireGestureToFail:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression




(lldb) expr [((id)0x7fe110297360) requireGestureToFail:((id)0x7fe10e842c00)]
error: no known method '-requireGestureToFail:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144892/how-to-send-a-message-to-an-object-in-lldb-console

Comment: It's not a duplicate as the question is only about *sending* a message to a object defined by a pointer, but OP also wants to pass such an object as a method's *parameter*.

Answer (score 2):

Then, why don't you cast it to a proper type instead?

```
exp -- [(UIGestureRecognizer *)address1 requireGestureToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)address2];
```

If you'd like to play a little more and call this method by it's address (assuming you still know all the types), here's an example.

Given the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]];
    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    UIGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(windowTapped:)];
    [[self window] addGestureRecognizer:gr];
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and setting a brakpoint right after adding the gesture recognizer to the window, here's what you can do:

```
(lldb) po [self window]
<UIWindow: 0x7ffd2acaff50; frame = (0 0; 320 480); hidden = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ffd2acb6930>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7ffd2aca8ac0>>

(lldb) image lookup -v -r -n "-\[UIGestureRecognizer view\]"
1 match found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit:
        Address: UIKit[0x00000000003c5c03] (UIKit.__TEXT.__text + 3946627)
        Summary: UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer view]`
         Module: file = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit", arch = "x86_64"
         Symbol: id = {0x000050db}, range = [0x0000000107ee4c03-0x0000000107ee4c14), name="-[UIGestureRecognizer view]"

(lldb) exp UIView *(*$m)(id, SEL) = (UIView *(*)(id, SEL))0x0000000107ee4c03
(lldb) exp SEL $s = @selector(view)
(lldb) p gr
(UIGestureRecognizer *) $1 = 0x00007ffd2ad38c90
(lldb) exp -- $m((id)0x00007ffd2ad38c90, $s)
(UIView *) $2 = 0x00007ffd2acaff50
(lldb) po $2
<UIWindow: 0x7ffd2acaff50; frame = (0 0; 320 480); hidden = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ffd2acb6930>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7ffd2aca8ac0>>

(lldb)
```

Basically what you do is, find the address of the method in memory (image lookup command, -v switch), create a temporary debugger variable (i.e $m here) of a proper type, and then using the 2 hidden arguments that you have to pass to each ObjC method call, call this method. As you can see comparing the addresses, you're getting the original window back as intended. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this now:
(lldb) exp -- [((UIGestureRecognizer *)0x7fe110297360) requireGestureToFail:((UIGestureRecognizer *)0x7fe10e842c00)]
error: no known method '-requireGestureToFail:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression


and then this:

Comment: exp [((UIGestureRecognizer *)0x7fe110297360) requireGestureToFail:((UIGestureRecognizer *)0x7fe10e842c00)]
error: no known method '-requireGestureToFail:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Are you sure these are really UIGestureRecognizer objects addresses? I've run a quick check and it works ok:  `(lldb) p gr1
(UITapGestureRecognizer *) $0 = 0x00007fc3a25411b0  
(lldb) p gr2 (UITapGestureRecognizer *) $1 = 0x00007fc3a2541da0  
(lldb) exp [(UIGestureRecognizer *)0x00007fc3a25411b0 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)0x00007fc3a2541da0]  
(lldb) c  
Process 80231 resuming  
`

Comment: You can try running `(lldb) po [(NSObject *)address class]` to see what you're really dealing with.

Comment: The expression parser is complaining about not knowing the RETURN TYPE of the method you are trying to call.  That's important because different return types have different calling conventions, and if we get the return type wrong it will corrupt the stack.  Try adding a cast of the return type to your method invocation as well.  Note, maciejs is doing that in his very clever little example, which is why that works when your attempts don't.

Comment: po [(NSObject *)0x7e244180 class]
UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer
p gr1 (UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer *) $0 = 0x7e244180
error: unexpected interface name 'UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer': expected expression
error: expected expression
error: 2 errors parsing expression
gr1 (UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer *) $0 = 0x7e244180
error: 'gr1' is not a valid command.
(lldb) (UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer *) $0 = 0x7e244180
error: '(UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer' is not a valid command.

Comment: (lldb) p (UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer *) $0 = 0x7e244180
error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: @maciejs - I checked and indeed they are the classes I expected